# issue In Maven POM.xml

Tags: svn, maven, struts2, pom.xml

I came across the below piece of code in my pom.xml

> ```
> <scm>
>        <connection>scm:svn:https://struts2webflow.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</connection>
>        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://struts2webflow.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</developerConnection>
>        <url>http://struts2webflow.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</url>
>     </scm>
> ```

I tried to understand the usage of scm but I'm not able to. My application uses struts2, spring 3 and hibernate. So what exactly is the use of pointing to struts2webflow??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's supposed to reference the version control system (aka software configuration management) of *your* project.

In your case, it's erroneous listing the version control system of struts2webflow, and is most likely as a result of someone duplicating the struts2webflow project's pom.xml, and forgetting to update the SCM section appropriately.

From my daily use, the  section is used only for the Maven release plug-in (there are likely other uses, but I don't know about them), so if you don't use the Maven release plug-in (`mvn release:prepare`, `mvn release:perform` etc), then it likely won't hurt anything.

I'd just remove it to avoid confusion for future developers.

Comment: It's also helpful to show what has [changed](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/changelog.html) and furthermore on the web site of the project it  shows where to find the code apart from the release plugin. If you correctly fill in the information you can use the release plugin to created branches etc. (release:branch).